# How to shrink the width size hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, block

I'm pretty fresh to html/css programming, so please forgive me for if this is a rookie mistake.

I've started a new webpage - http://robingham.co.uk/LUUCC4/index.php

I've decided to attempt to get the fixed navigation and menu bar sorted out first.

I want the menu button and the logo for the site to be within the fixed navigation bar. As you can see, i've pretty much sorted it out. There are a few minor things i need to do, like align the menu button. But functionality it seems to be working fine.

The issue that i'm attempting to fix at the moment is that the logo has a screen width sized hyperlink area. I've added a hyperlink to the logo so that users can go back to the home page by clicking it. I also want the logo to be horizontally centre regardless of the size of the screen. I believe the issue has something to do with the fact that i had to use `display: block;` to get the horizontal centre alignment to work but i'm not sure how to fix the hyperlink.

How do i fix it please?

Thanks

My index.php is.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC3/media/favicon.ico">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC3/styles/general_formatting.css"/>
    <title>LUUCC-Build</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC3/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC3/scripts/menu_function.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="header_bar">
        <img class="icon-menu" src="media/menu.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Menu button"/>
        <!--<a href="http://www.robingham.co.uk"><img id="header_bar_menu" src="media/menu.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Menu button"/></a>-->
        <div><a href="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC/index.php"><img id="header_bar_logo" src="media/header_bar_logo.png" width="315" height="65" alt="LUUCC logo"/></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <!-- Menu icon -->
      <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC3/media/close.png">
      </div>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>




    </div id="body_material">
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test3</p>
    <p>test4</p>
    <p>test5</p>
    <p>test6</p>
    <p>test7</p>
    <p>test8</p>
    <p>test9</p>
    <p>test10</p>
    <p>test221</p> <!--Removed some of these for the sake of the post-->
    <p>test221</p>
    <p>test221</p>
    <p>test221</p>
    <p>test221</p>
    </div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

My CSS code is.

```
body {
    background-color: #00FFF0; /*#f6f6f6*/
}

#header_bar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    height: 65px; /**/
    background-color: #FFFFFF; /*FFFFFF*/
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#header_bar_menu{
    display: inline-block;
    /*vertical-align: 9px;
    margin-left: 10px;*/
    border:4px solid #000000;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#header_bar_logo {
    /*display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 500px;*/
    /*display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;*/
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -95px; /*-60*/
}

.menu {
  background: #202024; 
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  top: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 /**/
.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I had a little copy and paste error in my code with some of my directories.

Ray's solution worked like magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6; /*#f6f6f6*/
}

#header_bar {
 z-index: 1;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 top: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 height: 65px;/**/
 background-color: #FFF;/*FFFFFF*/
 border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

#header_bar_menu{
 display: inline-block;
 /*vertical-align: 9px;
 margin-left: 10px;*/
 border:4px solid #000000;
 margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#header_bar_logo {
 /*display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 500px;*/
 /*display: inline-block;
 text-align:center;*/
 /* display: block; */
 /* margin-left: auto; */
 /* margin-right: auto; */
 /* margin-top: -95px; *//*-60*/
}

.menu {
  background: #202024; /* url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png') repeat left top;*/
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  top: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 /**/
.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* padding-bottom: 25px; */
  /* padding-left: 25px; */
  /* padding-top: 25px; */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<base href="http://robingham.co.uk/LUUCC4/index.php"/>
<div id="header_bar">
     <img class="icon-menu" src="media/menu.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Menu button"/>
  <!--<a href="http://www.robingham.co.uk"><img id="header_bar_menu" src="media/menu.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Menu button"/></a>-->
  <a href="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC4/index.php"><img id="header_bar_logo" src="media/header_bar_logo.png" width="315" height="65" alt="LUUCC logo"/></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="menu">
      <!-- Menu icon -->
      <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="http://www.robingham.co.uk/LUUCC4/media/close.png">
      </div>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 

 </div id="body_material">
 <p>test1</p>
 <p>test2</p>
 <p>test3</p>
 <p>test4</p>
 <p>test5</p>

 </div>
```

Comment: I pressed enter too quickly.
That's great thank you. Worked a treat!
Thanks for the pointer towards the base tag. Nice.
Ps. I do know that i don't need to explicitly state where my resources are because it should stem from the root folder. But as you've guessed from my slip up in the copy and paste, i'm running multiple versions of the same website, where once i've got something working, i move to a new folder for the next section, so the old folder becomes a backup of the current state.
Also thanks for giving me the code to align the menu button. 
Thanks.

Comment: I just added the base tag so the images would load when running the snippet here on stack overflow. ;)

I'd appreciate it if you'd officially accept my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm relatively new to this site. I thought I already had done. I think I have now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the link and the logo, like so:

```
<a>
    <img src="this_is_my_logo.png" />
</a>
```